# Running Kotlin function inside a Java class in a Kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I want to run a Kotlin function inside a Java class.
I know how to set it up but I believe the issue is my `build.gradle.kts` ?

When I run the Java function...this is the error I get:

```
Runner.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        int result = MyKotlinKt.add(5, 8);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable MyKotlinKt
  location: class Runner
```

Here are my files:

**MyKotlin.kt** Kotlin file

```
package com.example


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var result = max(8,65)
    println(result)
}

fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int= a+b
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = if(a>b) a else b
```

**Runner** Java file

```
package com.example;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int result = MyKotlinKt.add(5, 8);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts** file

```
plugins {
    id("com.example.kotlin-library-conventions")
}

dependencies {
    api("org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter")
    api("org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-plugin-spin")
    api("org.camunda.spin:camunda-spin-dataformat-json-jackson")
    api(project(":service"))
    testImplementation(project(":testing"))
    implementation("org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.27")
}

tasks.register<Test>("dmnValidation") {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags("dmnValidation")
    }
}
```

I tried watching videos, searched everywhere to figure out the problem.

Comment: if a Kotlin file has a main inside it, I think that it might be renamed to Main by the compiler, but not sure. Try to specify the package in the call `int result = com.package.MyKotlinKt.add(5, 8);`. Another thing that you could try is to annotate the kotlin file with `@file:JvmName("MyKotlinFile")`, then you would do `int result = MyKotlinFile.add(5, 8);` (of course, name it whatever you want).

Comment: We need more details on your project structure. Are both files in the same Gradle module? Could you build a jar file and see what's inside?

Comment: I did all the suggestions, when I do `javac Runner.java`, it doesn't compile because of that error

Comment: Wait, you compile it manually using javac?

Comment: With Javac, it didn't work. I had to put the kotlin file in a kotlin directory and Java file in Java directory for it to work. Having it one directory didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was was have the Java file in a java directory and kotlin file in a Kotlin directory for it to work